# Connecting database to HoloLens

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to find the best way to connect a database to my app (developed through Unity) for HoloLens.
My first thoughts were SharePoint or Azure.

I don't know the best option or if there is another better.
Does someone know it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you store your data, how you control the data, how the load is.

The first choice is public cloud solution, agree with your thoughts. For example, Azure DB can provide the stable data storage service, your app just need to consume REST API to access data, a reference to [Azure SQL Database REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/).

The more troublesome solution is, build the database server and write your Web API to control and access the data. You may have to take care of data security, data accessibility, load balancing.

Comment: For sure. I need to take care of that.
I need to build an FBX DB. So, probably Azure DB could be the best option.
Thanks